# How to change label of the Button on DefaultFailurePage.pcf

Tags: guidewire

When im getting application error in DefaultFailurePage.pcf while Policy center page navigation 
But i can't to identifying that page button where mentioned in designing in DefaultFailurePage.pcf and referenced page. 
Please let me know how to change that button Label and where ?

Answer (score 0):

DefaultFailurePage has ErrorTabBar.pcf.

You can change the button labels directly in PCF file or change the display key for your language, (displaykey.Web.TabBar.Help, displaykey.Web.TabBar.About, displaykey.Web.TabBar.Logout(entity.User.util.CurrentUser), displaykey.Web.TabBar.PartialLogout)